# Prove that $\text{Arg}(z_1 z_2) = \text{Arg}(z_1) + \text{Arg}(z_2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $\operatorname{Re}(z_1) > 0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(z_2) > 0$ prove that $\operatorname{Arg}(z_1 z_2) = \operatorname{Arg}(z_1) + \operatorname{Arg}(z_2) $

Now, I know that $ \operatorname{arg}(z_1) = \operatorname{Arg}(z_1) + 2\pi n_1$ and $ \operatorname{arg}(z_2) = \operatorname{Arg}(z_2) + 2\pi n_2$ where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are integers. Its given that $ \operatorname{arg}(z_1 z_2) = \operatorname{arg}(z_1) + \operatorname{arg}(z_2)$. It follows that

$$ \operatorname{arg}(z_1 z_2) = \operatorname{Arg}(z_1)+\operatorname{Arg}(z_2) + 2\pi (n_1 + n_2)$$

Also, we can use the fact that $\operatorname{arg}(z_1 z_2) = \operatorname{Arg}(z_1 z_2) +2\pi n$
where $n$ is some integer. So, combining, we get

$$\operatorname{Arg}(z_1 z_2) +2\pi n = \operatorname{Arg}(z_1)+\operatorname{Arg}(z_2) + 2\pi (n_1 + n_2) $$

Now, I don't know how to use the conditions given $\operatorname{Re}(z_1) > 0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(z_2) > 0$  to get the conclusion.

Comment: Why don't you use $r_1e^{i \theta_1} \cdot r_2e^{i \theta_2}=r_1r_2e^{i (\theta_1+\theta_1)}$?

Comment: @datboi, ok. But how does that help ?

Comment: Don't you see the arguments getting added?

Comment: $-\pi < \text{Arg}(z) \leq \pi$ is the principal argument of $z$. Its true that $\text{arg}(z_1 z_2) = \text{arg}(z_1) + \text{arg}(z_2)$ , but this is not true for the principal argument always. This problem shows that its only valid in special case

Comment: In your post you should clarify the distinction between $\text{Arg}$ and $\text{arg}$. It's very easy to dismiss the difference as a typo, however going by your comment above $\text{Arg}$ is the principal argument. That might also be why you're getting answers that you don't find appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear from the comments that you are confused with the extra $2n\pi$ in the expression

Generally,

$$\boxed{\operatorname{Arg}(z_1 z_2) = \operatorname{Arg}(z_1) + \operatorname{Arg}(z_2)} $$

---

The sum may exceed $\pi$, when at least one of the two angles exceed $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or go below $-\pi$, when at least one of the two angles is lesser than $\frac{-\pi}{2}$.However in LHS, we have the argument operator, which yields a value in $(-\pi,\pi]$

To fix this, we add a term $2n\pi$, which helps us convert RHS to a value in given range.

Note that $n \in \lbrace-1,0,1\rbrace$, since the sum can neither exceed $2\pi$, nor go below $-2\pi$

More intuitively, if RHS yields an angle not in range, just convert it to its principal value

Answer (score 0):

Let $$z_k = r_k(\cos\varphi_k + i\sin \varphi_k), \ \ k \in \{1,2\}$$

Then, observe that

$$z_1z_2=r_1r_2(\cos(\varphi_1+\varphi_2) + i\sin (\varphi_1+\varphi_2))$$

This implies $\operatorname{Arg}(z_1 z_2) = \operatorname{Arg}(z_1) + \operatorname{Arg}(z_2)$

Comment: Look at my comment above. This is not valid in general for principal argument. If $z_1 = -1$ and $z_2 = i$ then $\text{Arg}(z_1 z_2) = \text{Arg}(-i) = - \pi/2$ but $\text{Arg}(z_1) + \text{Arg}(z_2) = \pi + \pi/2 = 3\pi/2$

Comment: @user9026 The principal value of $3\pi/2$ is $-\pi/2$

Comment: @datboi I have given the example from the book "Complex Variables and Applications" by Brown and Churchill. I think you probably have another meaning for Arg in mind.

Comment: I'm adding an answer. I hope it will clear your doubts

Answer (score 0):

@DatBoi is right.
You see any complex number $z$ can be written as $z=|z|(\cos (\arg (z)) + i \sin (\arg (z) )$, where $|z|$ is the *modulus* of $z$ or the distance of $z$ from the Origin in the Argand Plane.
From the [Euler's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), we see that: $$\cos (\arg (z)) + i \sin (\arg (z))=e^{i(\arg (z))} $$
Hence, the number $z$ can be written as $z=|z|e^{i(\arg (z))}$. Now let's consider 2 numbers $z_1 = r_1 e^{i\theta_1}$ and  $z_2 = r_2 e^{i\theta_2}$, where $r_k$ and $\theta_k$ are the modulus and argument respectively of $z_k$.

Let their product be ${z_1}{z_2}=z=re^{i\theta}$, $r$ and $\theta$ being the modulus and argument of $z$, respectively. If we now substitute the values of $z_1$ and $z_2$ into the equation for $z$, we get: $${r_1}{r_2}e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}=z=re^{i\theta}$$
Thus, we get $r={r_1}{r_2}$ and $\theta ={\theta_1}+{\theta_2}$.
Therefore, $$\arg (z)=\arg ({z_1}{z_2})=\arg (z_1)+\arg (z_2)$$